# Fully fork a git repo?

Tags: git

I've not quite managed to piece together what I want to know from the multitude of answers on here and blog posts, so I'm asking this question:

How do I fork a git repo such that I get all the branches & tags of the upstream?

What I've tried is:

```
git init
git remote add origin <ORIGIN_URL> # i.e. my repo
git remote add upstream <UPSTREAM_URL> # i.e. the repo I want to fork
git fetch upstream
git push --all origin
```

But that last line fails when I would expect it to work. I get this:

```
$ git push --all origin
No refs in common and none specified; doing nothing.
Perhaps you should specify a branch such as 'master'.
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
error: failed to push some refs to <ORIGIN_URL>
```

Any ideas?

EDIT:

Maybe you can think of this question as "What does GitHub actually do when you click the fork button?", as that's the behaviour I am trying to replicate.

Comment: I think all you need to do is a "git clone <origin_url>"

that will download the complete remote repo with all branches and tags (therefore "clone").

I might got your question wrong :)

Comment: Sorry I forgot a `git fetch upstream` which I did. That not going to do basically the same thing?

Comment: it will. it is just more handy to just clone a remote repo compared to initialize one locally, adding the upstream urls and then fetching the remote. thats all done with just "clone".

after the clone you will use fetch to obtain the remote changes and download it into the local clone of the repo. so the answer would be yes i guess

Comment: Depending on how the last fails, you might have the upstream be a real repo people work in (so pushing there is really not a good idea) or where pushing is just not allowed. What is the error?

Comment: Upstream is of course a real repo, which I'm forking. Origin is my repo an is completely empty and I have full access to it.

Comment: "Real" in the sense "people are working **in** it"? If so, you better not push to it. Just imagine someone moving the branch you're working on while you were editing files... In default configuration Git rejects push attempts to non-bare (or "real working") repositories

Comment: I'm not trying to push to upstream; I'm trying to push to origin, i.e. my repo where I am trying to fork upstream to.

Comment: According to the error message, I seem to have NO local branches which correspond to the remote branches at all. Which is to be expected: you just added a remote and fetched. You have actually do something on a local branch, derived from a remote branch.

Comment: You can give -t option to git checkout when creating a local branch, to automatically setup a configuration for a pushing, but you might find it more revealing to just edit .git/config by hand and taking a quick look at the manpages of checkout and branch commands (i.e. `git help checkout`)

Comment: And BTW, `--mirror` will setup all branches correctly, minus working directory. For that, just clone the upstream. BTW, I think github does the mirror thing

Comment: Yeh so I could do `--mirror` then change the auto-created `origin` remote's name to `upstream` and then add my `origin` remote then finally push to `origin`? Or... is `--bare` what I want maybe?

Comment: `--bare` is same as normal clone, just without working directory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I've come up with as the best way to do what I wanted which seems to work and gets a similar behaviour to what GitHub does:

```
git clone --mirror <UPSTREAM> myrepo
cd myrepo
git remote rename origin upstream
git remote add origin <MY_ORIGIN>
git push --all
git push --tags
```

And then tweak the `.git/config` to change the `upstream` remote to not mirror anymore as that's certainly not what I want now.

Comment: If you try to do that inside a git repo, all commands past `cd myrepo` will still refer to that git repo above. You have to give `--bare` to all commands after: `git --bare remote ...`

Comment: This will instruct git to not look up for a .git in the directories above.

Comment: I didn't have to do that. (`$ git --version` => `git version 1.7.9.6 (Apple Git-31.1)`)

Comment: That's because you are lucky and never work with embedded repositories.

Comment: What is an embedded repository and why would that make a difference here?

Comment: A repo which is inside another git. Not as git submodule, just inside. Used in test suites, infrastructure maintainance (by Git itself it for test suites, for one)

Comment: It wont make difference _here_. It is just an advice for the future, which can save you quite a lot of typing, should you slip a command without `--bare` in such a situation

Comment: I'm confused by that. Do you mean there'd be a `.git` inside the folder when you checkout with `--bare`? That's the only way I can see there being a requirement for `--bare` otherwise it can infer it from there being no `.git` and the rest of the folder looking like a git repo.

Comment: Oh right. I never thought that would be possible unless you versioned a `.git` itself. Although then you probably wouldn't want `--bare` anyway.

Answer (score 4):

Try a mirror:

```
git clone --mirror
```

This way, the remote (named `origin`) is created without a namespace for branches. IOW, the refs/heads/master in the mirror corresponds exactly (and is bound to) the refs/heads/master in the origin repository.

Now just use this repository instead of original upstream repository. If you ever want to update the mirror, do something like this in it:

```
cd upstream-mirror.git && git --bare fetch upstream
```

Warning: if you ever push into your mirror, modifying the upstreams branches, the upstream repo and your mirror will diverge. and push (without `-f` option) will fail, to prevent that.

Mirror is actually an exact mirror of the upstream repo, with you, as its owner, having an option to modify it.

Comment: This isn't quite a full answer yet. It does not explain how I mirror the remote and then push this to my own repo on my server. I'll accept if it is expanded with a full example.

Comment: You cannot _push_ it. Just copy it. You can even run this command **on** your server.

Comment: Ugh I don't think you understand what I am trying to do. I want to clone a remote repo onto my local machine and then push this to my server. Sure I could run the clone on my server but surely I shouldn't *have* to?

Comment: I afraid so. I'm completely lost as to what you're trying to achieve by _pushing to your server_.

Comment: If you wish, I retract my answer.

Comment: No need to retract - thanks for helping :-). I do find it strange that there's no way to do what I want without `clone`-ing on the server. By the way, `fetch` has no option `--bare` as you mention in your answer.

Comment: Oh, it kind of does. It is to be given *before* `fetch`, not after, though